# How to pass array values through a contructor

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

The code that I have will multiply two matrices in an array and output the value. What I would like to do next is split the code into two classes. I would like a class that can take the user input and pass the array value to a constructor in another class and then compute the same value. I know how to grab the return type from the second class but have no idea on how to pass the values from the array for computation. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MatrixApp
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int m, n, p, q; 
      int sum = 0, c, d, k;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix");
      m = in.nextInt();
      n = in.nextInt();

      int first[][] = new int[m][n];

      System.out.println("Enter the elements of first matrix");

      for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
         for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
            first[c][d] = in.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of second matrix");
      p = in.nextInt();
      q = in.nextInt();

      if ( n != p )
         System.out.println("Matrices with entered orders can't be    multiplied with each other.");
      else
      {
         int second[][] = new int[p][q];
         int multiply[][] = new int[m][q];

         System.out.println("Enter the elements of second matrix");

         for ( c = 0 ; c < p ; c++ )
            for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
               second[c][d] = in.nextInt();

         for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
         {
            for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
            {   
               for ( k = 0 ; k < p ; k++ )
               {
                  sum = sum + first[c][k]*second[k][d];
               }

               multiply[c][d] = sum;
               sum = 0;
            }
         }

         System.out.println("Product of entered matrices:-");

         for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
         {
            for ( d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
               System.out.print(multiply[c][d]+"\t");

                System.out.print("\n");
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? I am failing to understand it completely.

Comment: I would like to be able to take the input values assigned to the arrays and pass them to another class for calculations. I would like my main method to be used to just call return values and not handle the calculations. Hope that helps

Comment: A "class" doesn't return values. You don't pass a value "from an array". Please clarify, ideally by providing the method signatures.

Comment: A "class" can have methods that return values, I am just trying to figure out how to pass the values to a constructor. In my code, the user will input the values. I would like to pass these values to another method in another class. I know how to call them, but setting them is the issue.

Comment: @laune his question is extremely simple to understand. I do not understand your confusion and TejjD's confusion

Comment: @TejjD see above comment

Comment: he just wants `public void classConstructor(arrayType arrayName[])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understood you correctly, but if you want to pass the array values to constructor and do the calculation, then below is one such implementation, I have used two classes as per your needs.
This is a very quick implementation, so I have not optimized it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class TestMatrixApp {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
int m, n, p, q;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix");
m = input.nextInt();
n = input.nextInt();

System.out
    .println("Enter the number of rows and columns of second matrix");
p = input.nextInt();
q = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the elements of first matrix");

int first[][] = new int[m][n];
for (int c = 0; c < m; c++)
    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
    first[c][d] = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the elements of second matrix");
int second[][] = new int[p][q];

for (int c = 0; c < p; c++)
    for (int d = 0; d < q; d++)
    second[c][d] = input.nextInt();

MatrixApp matrixApp = new MatrixApp(first, second, m, n, p, q);
}
```

}

The next class

public class MatrixApp {

```
public MatrixApp(int first[][], int second[][], int m, int n, int p, int q) {
doMatrixMultiply(first, second, m, n, p, q);
}

public void doMatrixMultiply(int first[][], int second[][], int m, int n, int p, int q)
{

   if ( n != p )
      System.out.println("Matrices with entered orders can't be    multiplied with each other.");
   else
   {
      int multiply[][] = new int[m][q];
      int sum = 0;
      for ( int c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
      {
         for (int d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
         {   
            for (int k = 0 ; k < p ; k++ )
            {
               sum = sum + first[c][k]*second[k][d];
            }

            multiply[c][d] = sum;
            sum = 0;
         }
      }

      System.out.println("Product of entered matrices:-");

      for (int c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
      {
         for (int d = 0 ; d < q ; d++ )
            System.out.print(multiply[c][d]+"\t");

             System.out.print("\n");
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Really all you need is the one class that has all the code for your matrices, whatever you want them to have, although you do not really need two classes for this. The class that handles computation really only needs constructor that looks like this. The argument is an integer (primitve data) matrix. Do keep in mind that the class that contains this constructor MUST have two private variables:

```
private int[][] matrixMult, int[][] matrixMult2;//private variables

public classObject(int matrixName[][], int matrixName2[][])
{
    matrixMult = matrixName;
    matrixMult2 = matrixName2;
}
```

Then it needs a computation method which you seem to have down already. Then you simply open a class with a main method, have a user input the matrix values for both the matrices then put them into the constructor. You can do as the answer from likeToCode does and have it do the math in the constructor, or you can call a multiplication method after doing your constructing with the above constructor. Also note, that the constructor I showed you just shows how to put a matrix into a constructor, you will need to add on whatever other values you require.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //create and fill matrices
    classObject bOB = new classObject(matrixOne, matrixTwo);//add on other values as needed
    System.out.println(bOB.multMatrices());

}
```

Here you have created an object of the second class you wanted, and done multiplication. I do not understand why you want two classes, but it is really rather simple in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the array with [] in the constructor and call it without them, for instance:

```
void receiveArray(int[] array){
   //doStuff
}

private void callerMethod(){
   . . .
   int[] array = new int[size];
   //Populate
   receiveArray(array);
}
```

Comment: Extreeeeemly helpful.

Comment: Rather vague. Where does the `size` variable come from? The description for your answer detailing what needs to be done is not straightforward. Improve the answer please. Also, OP wants a constructor, where is your constructor?

Comment: Well, I didn't think I had to be that explicit, is it really necessary to explain where the size is coming from? The key of his problem was how to pass the array as a parameter, which like it or not is what this very brief code explains...

Comment: Ah, I understand your reasoning now. I understood where the `size` was coming from, it just seemed that since the OP did not understand passing arrays as parameters that he may have need more explicit explanation, hence the 26 page long text for my answer. :)